# Fixed UIToolbar and slideup UIViewController panels, over a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am looking to create a UINavigationController iPhone app with some UI that, as far as I can tell, is slightly strange. Despite my best efforts to figure out a *good* solution to this problem, I can't seem to find the *right* solution, so would appreciate some advice.

There will be a (customized) toolbar at the bottom with several buttons. When a button is pressed it will present a modal panel view, which slides up, closing other open panels, but leaving the toolbar visible. When the same toolbar button is pressed again the modal view slides down again. The modal views are used to choose a new UIViewController to push onto the UINavigationController. These modal slideup-panels can also be opened by buttons in the controllers that have been pushed onto the UINavigationController.

The main problem, as far as I see it, is presenting and dismissing the modal UIViewControllers so that the toolbar remains. Also - who does the presenting/dismissing? The App Delegate or the root ViewController, or someone else?

My initial (bad) solution was to have a root UIViewController that had a sub-UINavigationController whose view was used as a subview, and the toolbar & modal panels were just other subviews. But, for pre-iOS5 apps, sub-ViewControllers are bad and sick and wrong and evil (no matter how logical they seem).

Another (probably bad) option is to use a UINavigationController subclass as the root view controller, and have this handle all the toolbar functionality.

Any suggestions? Am I overlooking some obvious in-built functionality or a standard design concept?

Comment: On the subject of using UIViewController as a subview, this article covers the subject very well:

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Yeah I had read that before, and others like it, hence my 'bad/sick/wrong/evil' comment. I started working on a ViewCoordinator protocol for handling the toolbar/panels (see also: http://bit.ly/oVF1cU , http://bit.ly/qePDCg & http://slidesha.re/tMZdPo ), but became confused as to who should own these objects - a subclass of the NavController? Also, what view to add their views to, and if it was possible to load them from a nib. Maybe I need to bite the bullet and make it iOS 5 only...

Comment: Id strongly recommend against making it iOS 5 only. There is still a meaningful percentage of users running iOS 4 (and will be for some time). Subclassing UINavController is also a bad idea and Apple recommends against it. I'd personally just do away with navigation controllers and handle the display of views myself, using delegation  to send messages between your custom tab bar and the main view.

Comment: I agree that subclassing UINavController probably a bad idea. But I need the functionality of the UINavController, just with several views over the top. The real question is, who should own and manage those custom views, and to what view should they be added? The AppDelegate perhaps, as it is the only thing that is customizable and above the NavController. But then those views wont receive all the nice ViewController events (rotation etc) - which is the main reason for not doing nested ViewControllers! BAH, the screen-filling UIViewController rule is killing me.